# Setup barman backup when Posgres is running in Docker

Tags: database, docker, backup, database-backups, barman

I have a kubernetes cluster, with a pod running the postgres database, so in Docker. Obviously, I have the data mounted on the host.

I would like to setup Barman to have a backup solution for the DB.

I read the documentation about barman. According to the Design and architecture
section of http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.0/, I would like to go with the following architecture, because I have a large database and incremental backup is in our requirements. This is not possible with streaming backup strategy (Scenario 1: Backup via streaming protocol), even if they said it's better for Docker environments

[image]

My question is how can I setup this when postgres is running in Docker ? Because ofthe files that are mounted on the host, can I just ssh on the host to proceed to the backup ?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

You can't ssh to the host to proceed since it has to be initiated & coordinated by the PostgreSQL server running in the container.

You can however setup passwordless ssh connectivity (with ssh keys) along with streaming connectivity between PostgreSQL & Barman containers and implement the stated architecture.

This entails building & running a PostgreSQL container with ssh server & rsync along with barman.

There are many versions of implementations out there that have done it, but if you wanted to do something from the scratch & keep the image simple, please take a look at the implementation of the above shared in the below git repo,

https://github.com/softwarebrahma/PostgreSQL-Disaster-Recovery-With-Barman

Thanks